# Programa .jar criado não executa!

Tags: arquivo, netbeans, diretório

Fiz o seguinte programa em java para trocar automaticamente um arquivo em um diretório do computador:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (!new File("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Network\\Connections\\Pbk").exists()) {
            new File("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Network\\Connections\\Pbk").mkdirs();
        } else {

        }

File r = new File("C:\\Users\\ALMIRANTE\\Desktop\\rasphone.pbk");
File d = new File("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Network\\Connections\\Pbk\\ra
sphone.pbk");

        if (d.exists())
        d.delete();

        FileChannel rChannel = null;
        FileChannel dChannel = null;


        try {
            rChannel = new FileInputStream(r).getChannel();
            dChannel = new FileOutputStream(d).getChannel();
            rChannel.transferTo(0, rChannel.size(),
            dChannel); //System.out.println("ok");

       } finally {
            if (rChannel != null && rChannel.isOpen())
            rChannel.close();
            if (dChannel != null && dChannel.isOpen())
            dChannel.close();//System.out.println("ok");
       }
 }


}
```

Funcionou corretamente pelo Netbeans. Porém ao contruí-lo, ir na pasta "**dist**" e clicar no arquivo .jar gerado, nada ocorre, isto é, o programa não faz o que devia fazer. Apenas uma tela preta do próprio windows abre e fecha rapidamente.

Pelas minhas pesquisas vi que poderia ser algo relacionado à classe principal, sobretudo que a mesma certamente não estaria definida. Porém, já defini a classe, que é: **rasphonefile.RasphoneFile**.

Ao ir no cmd e colocar ***java -jar RasphoneFile.jar***, ocorre o seguinte erro:

***Unable to access jar file RasphoneFile.jar***

Ao executar, também no prompt de comando, o código ***java tfv RasphoneFile.jar***, o qual testa o conteúdo do arquivo, consta que ***não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal***.

Alguém sabe quais as possíveis causas disso? Obrigado!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Fiz todo o processo em .bat: muito mais simples e funcional, já que os próprios sistemas já tem o suporte para ler esse tipo de arquivo.

https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-arquivos-bat-e-programacao-em-lotes/24800

Segue o código:

```
@echo off
xcopy  "%userprofile%\Desktop\ARQUIVOS\arquivo.pdf" "C:\ProgramData\Adobe\" /y 
exit
```

**@echo off** serve para que não sejam exibidas linhas de comando na tela.

**Xcopy**: É um comando que copia arquivos e diretórios, incluindo subdiretórios.

**"%userprofile%\Desktop\ARQUIVOS\arquivo.pdf"**: É o caminho do arquivo de origem, o qual eu queria copiar. A parte **“%userprofile%”** dele, serve para que se consiga executar o programa em qualquer computador, já que, se eu o criasse usando o caminho padrão da máquina do João: **“c:\users\Joao\Desktop\arquivo.txt”**, e eu fosse executar na máquina da Maria, cujo usuário é Maria, não daria certo, pois o caminho poderia ser:  **“c:\users\Maria\Desktop\arquivo.txt”**. Com esse código genérico, funciona com qualquer nome, porque ele já busca o usuário específico da máquina.

**"C:\ProgramData\Adobe\"**: É o diretório de destino, ou seja, onde quero salvar esse arquivo. Repare que a última pasta, a **“Adobe”**, possui uma \ no final, a fim de referir que a mesma é um diretório. Caso colocasse apenas **Adobe**, poderia dar erro.

**/y**: O xcopy possui vários parâmetros. Um deles é o **/y**, que bloqueia a solicitação de permissão do batch para substituir o arquivo de destino já existente. Têm o **/e**, que copia todos os diretórios, mesmo que estejam vazios, o **/t**, que copia apenas diretórios (com ou sem arquivos, sendo que, no último caso, deve-se usar o **/e** junto dele).

**exit**: só para fechar a tela!

Segue link dos parâmetros e mais informações, bem como outros comandos em batch (.bat).

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Para criar um arquivo.bat, basta abrir o bloco de notas, fazer o código e salvar como .bat. Se precisar editá-lo, clique no mesmo com o botão direito e vá em editar.

Segue mais um .bat que fiz. Por meio dele importei uma tarefa sem precisar abrir o agendador (o que demora muito).

Segue o código:

```
@echo off
schtasks.exe /Create /XML %userprofile%\Desktop\ARQUIVOS\tarefamaluca.xml /tn "TAREFA MALUCA"
exit
```

**schtasks.exe** /Create XML Significa que o agendador será executado (**schtasks.exe**)

**/Create**: uma tarefa será criada/importada (a qual, antes de se tornar uma tarefa, é um documento XML;

XML por isso têm XML ali, porque ele vai ser importado;

**%userprofile%\Desktop\ARQUIVOS\tarefamaluca.xml /tn**: indica o caminho da tarefa, sendo o nome dessa **"tarefamaluca.xml"**;

**"TAREFA MALUCA"** é o nome/título que você atribui à tarefa;